# No puedo mostrar pagina al hacer clic en html

Tags: html, css

estoy editando una plantilla html para adaptarla a un proyecto personal, entonces cuando creo los diferentes botone para referenciarlos  a sus paginas, hay uno que no me permite enviarlo, al parecer esta bloqueado y he revisado todo el codigo html y css. favor ayudarme.

aqui esta el codigo html.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>Inicio</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>Servicios</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="register"><span>Registrarse</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact"><span>Contactenos</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="Inicio.html"> <span>Login</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                </nav>
```

[image: cuando le doy clic a login no abre ni te envia a la pagina que quiero]

Este es el template que uso: https://freehtml5.co/preview/?item=elate-free-html5-bootstrap-template

Comment: Debes de ser mas especifico con tu problema.Cual no te permite enviar?

Comment: El de login, los demas estan de forma transition que van a la misma pagina, pero el de login no hace referencia.

Comment: Revisa tu css, busca propiedad `z-index` que esté relacionada con tus `<a>` `<li>` o `<div>` que contengan el enlace. Es importante que ningún valor de la propiedad sea negativa.

Comment: verifique todo y esta bien, aqui te adjunto el proyecto para que veas.

Comment: http://ge.tt/5QPJMUs2 ahi esta el link del template

Answer (score 2):

Lo que ocurre es que esa plantilla que estás usando está pensada para ser una única página y los enlaces del menú usan javascript para moverse dentro de la propia página y bloquean el comportamiento normal de los enlaces.

En el código he visto que el script se aplica a los enlaces del menú que no tengan la clase `external` por lo que lo más fácil para que no tengas que cambiar nada es poner esa clase al enlace que quieres que apunte a `login.html`:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="work"><span>Galeria</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>Servicios</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact"><span>Contactenos</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="external" href="login.html">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta por javascript.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>Inicio</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>Servicios</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="register"><span>Registrarse</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact"><span>Contactenos</span></a></li>
                    <li><a onclick="location.href='Inicio.html'"> <span>Login</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta línea estás haciendo referencia a `Inicio.html`  - donde está esa pagina, debe estar en el mismo directorio.

```
<li><a href="Inicio.html"> <span>Login</span></a></li>
```

*Están en la misma carpeta:*

[image: Están en la misma carpeta]

Comment: ahi esta la carperta, el index es el principal, e inicio la pagina de login la cual no me permite abrir

Comment: ¿Pero están ambas páginas (index y inicio) en la misma carpeta?. Asegurate también que se llama exactamente tal cual has escrito en el atributo `href` y que la extensión es `html`

Comment: Ya he revisado todo, estan en la misma carpeta y he probado con diferentes nombres e incluso paginas en blanco llamdas login.html, inicio.html. y nada. cuando creo un nuevo <li><a href="Inicio.html"> <span>Login</span></a></li>  parece como si estuviese bloqueado.

Comment: A qué te refieres con bloqueado? Le das al clic y no hace nada? Al pasar por encima del enlace te aparece el cursor tipo pointer?

Comment: si, cuando doy clic en login que es la pagina que quiero que salga, no funciona, cuando coloco el mouse aparece para darle clic y no hace nada.